# Area of trapezoid given all sides: Why is this an Olympiad problem?

Tags: contest-math

I was going through some Olympiad Maths and found this question:

> Given a trapezoid with its upper base $5$ cm long, lower base $10$ cm long, and its legs are $3$ and $4$ cm long. What is the area of this trapezoid?

Yeah, I know. There are equations to calculate this, I found [some equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637690/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-trapezoid-knowing-the-length-of-al) on Math Stack Exchange too.

What I don’t understand is that this is an Olympiad question. The proofs that I saw to create the formulae did not look like something that should appear in an Olympiad question. Am I missing something, or do I actually need to create my own formula to solve this question? Keep in mind that this is a timed test; if I was actually taking this test, I would have to solve this in 2 minutes maximum.

Comment: Try to make use of a $3-4-5$ right triangle.

Comment: Reading the Olympiad question, I assumed you wondered why it was an Olympiad problem because it is nearly trivial. But the last paragraph suggests that maybe you believe it is too difficult? Could you clarify?

Comment: In general, questions which implore us to get into the minds of the authors of texts or exams are off-topic here.  Such questions are not actually mathematics questions---we can't read other people's minds.  As such the question "Why is this an Olympiad question?" is off-topic.  If you are actually looking for a solution to the question posed, please edit the question to make it clear that this is the concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a parallelogram with the upper base and one of the trapezoid's legs as two of the parallelogram's sides.
[image: Diagram of parallelogram and trapezoid]
Notice the right-angle triangle? You can use this to find the height of the trapezoid, and thus its area.

Comment: Alternatively on joining CM we see several $3-4-5$ triangles. Hence area is $3 \times 6=18$.

Comment: @MyMolecules Thanks for your help as well!

Answer (score 3):

We join the midpoint of longer base to endpoints of shorter base and find that the trapezium is partitioned into three $3-4-5$ right triangles.

Hence area is $3 \times 6=18$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is easy to see it breaks into finding the areas of a rectangle and two right triangles, but stacking the right triangles together gives a $3-4-5$ triangle, whose area is easily measured. This area gives the height, which allows the rectangle to be measured easily as well. Shouldn't take much time I suppose.