# calculate height of ​trapezoid using different methods

Tags: geometry, area

I've been playing with this problem for a long time, but I don't see a solution yet.
Consider the sides of a trapezoid of lengths a and b, a > b (not heights) ( see edition (and the bases major "a" and minor "b"). Determine the height of this trapezoid using two different methods.
Don't use trigonometry

[image: trapezoid]

Can you help me

EDIT
**Typing error:
a and b sides, a and b are not heights, a>b, the bases greatest "p" and least "q"**
**There is also the image that refers to the data**

Comment: So each base has a corresponding lateral side with equal length? So the quadrilateral is both a trapezoid and a kite? So the quadrilateral is a parallelogram? So $a=b$ which is a contradiction of $a>b$?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are we saying the four sides have lengths $a,a,b,b$, with the 2nd and 4th sides parallel? And why does the body of the question ask for the height, when the title of the question asks for the area?

Comment: Do you mean you want to compute the area of a generic trapezoid, by knowing only its four sides? If so, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2637690/255730

Comment: It's really helpful to readers to draw and upload a picture of the problem along with the text.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted, Pamela?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is attached to the edition.

Firstly, it is well-known that we can calculate the height of a triangle with length of its sides fixed. To be specific, consider the fomula $$S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)},p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$$
Hence $h_a=2S/a. $

Then for the trapezoid, you can extend the two lateral sides to the intersection   and you'll get a small triangle with its sides easily calculated, thus you'll get the height of it. And the height of tragezoid is just some proportion of it.

Comment: It's preferable to use $s$ rather than $p$ since we are working with the semiperimeter rather than the perimeter.

Comment: @Nate Hmm...$p$ is rather popular in Chinese text books. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Label the vertices of the trapezoid $C,D,E,F$ so that $|CD|=b$, $|DE|=q$, $|EF|=a$, $|CF|=p$. Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to a point $G$ on $CF$, and one from $E$ to a point $H$ on $CF$. Let $DG=EH=x$, $CG=r,$ $FH=s$ (so $x$ is the height we're trying to find). We have
$$
r^2+x^2=b^2,\qquad s^2+x^2=a^2,\qquad r+q+s=p
$$
So $s=p-q-r$, so $(p-q-r)^2+x^2=a^2$. Multiply this out, replace $r^2+x^2$ with $b^2$, and solve for $r$, getting
$$
r={1\over2}{(p-q)^2-(a^2-b^2)\over p-q}
$$
Between this and $x=\sqrt{b^2-r^2}$, you get a formula for $x$ in terms of the givens, $a,b,p,q$.